# How to change Android Sherlock FragmentTabsPager tab text size and font?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-tabhost, android-style-tabhost

I've used Sherlock library in my Android project and I want to make the size of text in tab a little smaller.

This is FragmentTabsPager.java

```
package com.actionbarsherlock.sample.fragments;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabWidget;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

/**
 * Demonstrates combining a TabHost with a ViewPager to implement a tab UI
 * that switches between tabs and also allows the user to perform horizontal
 * flicks to move between the tabs.
 */
public class FragmentTabsPager extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    TabHost mTabHost;
    ViewPager  mViewPager;
    TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs_pager);
        mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();

        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mTabHost, mViewPager);

        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Messages"),
                FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("History"),
                LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Contacts"),
                LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Dialpad"),
                LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("More"),
                LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class, null);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
    }

    /**
     * This is a helper class that implements the management of tabs and all
     * details of connecting a ViewPager with associated TabHost.  It relies on a
     * trick.  Normally a tab host has a simple API for supplying a View or
     * Intent that each tab will show.  This is not sufficient for switching
     * between pages.  So instead we make the content part of the tab host
     * 0dp high (it is not shown) and the TabsAdapter supplies its own dummy
     * view to show as the tab content.  It listens to changes in tabs, and takes
     * care of switch to the correct paged in the ViewPager whenever the selected
     * tab changes.
     */
    public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
            implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private final Context mContext;
        private final TabHost mTabHost;
        private final ViewPager mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        static final class TabInfo {
            private final String tag;
            private final Class<?> clss;
            private final Bundle args;

            TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
                tag = _tag;
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

        static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
            private final Context mContext;

            public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
                mContext = context;
            }

            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                View v = new View(mContext);
                v.setMinimumWidth(0);
                v.setMinimumHeight(0);
                return v;
            }
        }

        public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager) {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mTabHost = tabHost;
            mViewPager = pager;
            mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
            tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
            String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // Unfortunately when TabHost changes the current tab, it kindly
            // also takes care of putting focus on it when not in touch mode.
            // The jerk.
            // This hack tries to prevent this from pulling focus out of our
            // ViewPager.
            TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
            int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
            widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
            widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    }
}
```

And here is corresponding layout xml:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And I've tried solution here https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/401
However, it's not working!

Any idea will be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem customizing my tabs.The code below changes tab colour,height and text colour.Hope it will help.

```
            View currentView;

        final int height = 60;
        for (int i = 0; i < tabChildrenCount; i++) {
            currentView = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams currentLayout = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) currentView.getLayoutParams();
            currentLayout.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 0);
           mTabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(true);
           setTabColor(mTabHost);
          mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = height;

        final TextView tv = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        if ( tv instanceof TextView ) {
          // just in case check the type

          // center text
          ((TextView) tv).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
          // wrap text
          ((TextView) tv).setSingleLine(false);
          // explicitly set layout parameters
          tv.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
          tv.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
      }
        }

    public static void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {
for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
{
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#558FBB")); //unselected
}
tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseCol

or("#236B8E")); // selected
}
```